# How to select data given several rows match?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a configuration table and a users table.

users:

```
| id |  name    |
|----|----------|
| 0  |  Bob     |
| 1  |  Ted     |
| 2  |  Sam     |
```

config:

```
| user_id |  name    | value |
|---------|----------|-------|
| 0       |  a       |   11  |
| 0       |  b       |   2   |
| 0       |  c       |   54  |
| 1       |  a       |   5   |
| 1       |  b       |   3   |
| 1       |  c       |   0   |
| 2       |  a       |   1   |
| 2       |  b       |   74  |
| 2       |  c       |   54  |
```

I normalized the configuration this way since the config will be of unknown amount, but I will have to query users based on this config, so it couldn't be stored in a serialized form.

My issue is how do I find users based on multiple rows? For instance:
Select all users with a > 4 and b < 5

This should return Bob and Ted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT us.name
FROM USERS us
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT name FROM CONFIG WHERE name='a' AND value>4 AND user_id=us.id)
AND  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM CONFIG WHERE name='b' AND value<5 AND user_id=us.id)
```

Alternatively, you can use two joins:

```
SELECT us.name
FROM USERS us, CONFIG c1, CONFIG c2
WHERE us.id=c1.user_id
AND c1.name='a'
AND c1.value<4
AND us.id=c2.user_id
AND c2.name='b'
AND c2.value>5
```

Comment: two joins will result in the same execution plan, but query is less readable (for my taste)

Comment: for my taste as well ;)

Comment: I prefer the joins, but explicit ones.

Answer (score 3):

Using groups:

```
  SELECT u.name 
    FROM users u
    JOIN config c
      ON c.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.name
  HAVING MAX(c.name = 'a' AND c.value > 4)
     AND MAX(c.name = 'b' AND c.value < 5)
```

Using joins:

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM users u
  JOIN config a
    ON a.user_id = u.id
   AND a.name = 'a'
   AND a.value > 4
  JOIN config b
    ON b.user_id = u.id
   AND b.name = 'b'
   AND b.value < 5
```

I prefer the `JOIN` method, as you can name each `JOIN` after the property and collect the conditions in the `JOIN`. You also don't have to worry about the `GROUP`s which makes it more flexible for aggregates.

A bonus over `EXISTS` is that you can easily access the properties of the config if you require further joins/calculations.

Answer (score 0):

you will need two `exists` statements for this:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM config
               WHERE user_id = u.id
                 AND name = 'a' AND value > 4)
     AND  EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM config
               WHERE user_id = u.id
                 AND name = 'b' AND value < 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

select u.name from users as u inner join config as c on u.id = c.user_id where (c.name = "a" and c.value > 4) or (c.name = "b" and c.value < 5);

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the following query achieves the result, as does not rely joining between the tables in any way.
to include more of "name" you could add another OR clause inside the HAVING.
NOTE: This has been tested on the W3Schools WebSQL Interface

```
SELECT 
    value,
    name,
    user_id 
FROM config

GROUP BY value, name, user_id

HAVING
(
    (value > 4 AND name = 'a')
    OR (value < 5 AND name = 'b')
 )
```

After ditching the grouping (thanks Arth)

```
SELECT 
    value,
    name,
    user_id 
FROM config


WHERE
(
    (value > 4 AND name = 'a')
    OR (value < 5 AND name = 'b')
 )
```

Comment: I'd be vary wary about grouping by value here, this solution breaks down if they are not unique in the config. You also return the same user_id multiple times which is worth mentioning.

Comment: you can extend the grouping to other columns to get around the duplicate issue. I assume the user_id is a desired output...i may be wrong - after reviewing the OP i see the names are the desired output...guess your solution is more correct here :)

Comment: In fact you may as well ditch the groups altogether and use a WHERE ... OR ... clause. Grouping is superfluous with this approach.